# How to make Nested for loop pattern

Tags: java

how to make following pattern in java using nested for loop

```
      1
     21
    321
   4321
  54321
 654321
```

I was trying it with this one.

```
for (int r = 1; r <= 6; r++) {
        for (int s = 6; s > row; s--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int c = 1; c<=r; c++) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

but output of this code was:

```
     1
    12
   123
  1234
 12345
123456
```

expected result:

```
     1
    21
   321
  4321
 54321
654321
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start at 6 and go down, then you need to start at `row` in this loop:

```
for (int col = 1; col<=row; col++) {
    System.out.print(col);
}
```

Change it to:

```
for (int col = row; col > 0; col--) {
    System.out.print(col);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only two nested loops are enough to achieve that pattern you asked for

```
for (int row = 1; row < 7; row++) {// for loop for rows
    for (int spaces = 6; spaces > 0; spaces--) {
        if(spaces> row)
           System.out.print(" ");
        else
           System.out.print(spaces);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: upvote for good solution but having 2 for loops is more efficient way because of breaks and jumps.